# How to implement exponentially decreasing weighted average

Tags: java, statistics, kotlin, weighted-average

I've been trying to implement a weighted average function using exponentially decreasing weights as described [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Exponentially_decreasing_weights).

I think I'm failing! I'm a bit too thick to fill in a few of the gaps that seem to be missing from the Wikipedia article, since it seems to be missing a nice clean one-line definition of what the function should produce given *m* samples, *ie* what does f(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ... x<sub>m</sub>) = ?.

Here's my attempt to implement it in Kotlin, where *numbers* contains my *m* samples, and *fraction* is the Δ referred to in the Wikipedia article:

```
fun weightedAverage(numbers: List<Long>, fraction: BigDecimal): Long? {
    if (! (zero < fraction && fraction < one)) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("fraction must be in (0..1), but $fraction is outside that range")
    }
    return when(numbers.size) {
        0 -> null
        1 -> numbers.first()
        else -> multiPointWeightedAverage(numbers, fraction)
    }
}

private fun multiPointWeightedAverage(numbers: List<Long>, fraction: BigDecimal): Long {
    val m = numbers.size
    var w = one - fraction
    val w_m = w.pow(m)
    val V1 = (one - w_m) / fraction
    var sum = w * BigDecimal(numbers[0])
    for (i in 1..m-1) {
        w /= V1
        sum += w * BigDecimal(numbers[1])
    }
    return sum.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toLong()
}
```

But I'm pretty sure this is wrong, because, *eg*, I expect `weightedAverage(listOf(1L, 1L, 1L), BigDecimal(0.9))` to produce the output 1, but it ends up spitting out 0.27125... which rounds down to zero.

Can you help me correct my implementation, hopefully explaining what wrong assumption or step I made?

Comment: That result sounds correct to me - your initial state is zero, so you're seeing your moving-average slowly ramp up.

Comment: Whoever downvoted me, could you possibly explain why so I don't repeat whatever it was that troubled you?